# extracting a user choice from variable class box

Tags: javascript

Truly a quirk of Javascript that goes above my head

I read into this and it seemed to do with cases in Javascript. \

Either way, I have multiple class div boxs and data filling each box. The code below outputs what the user chooses into console.

All good and well, however i am trying to extract the users choice and put it into a variable so what the user chose from the drop down can be used to inform other parts of my code. I dont know how to extract that information?

```
//Global variables 
classText = document.getElementsByClassName("searchText");
classBox = document.getElementsByClassName("searchBoxModule");

//HTML
            <div id="searchBox">
            <div class="searchBoxModule" onclick="firstBox()">
                <a class='searchText'></a>
            </div>
            <div class="searchBoxModule">
                <a class='searchText'></a>
            </div>
            <div class="searchBoxModule">
                <a class='searchText'></a>
            </div>
            <div class="searchBoxModule">
                <a class='searchText'></a>
            </div>
            <div class="searchBoxModule">
                <a class='searchText'></a>
            </div>

        </div>
//Javascript

for(var i = 0; i < classText.length; i++) {

classText[i].innerHTML = arrFiltered[i] || "";

console.log(i + arrFiltered[i]);

classBox[i].onclick = function (value) {


//if a search box is click do:
return function(){
    console.log(value);

    };

    //The below outputs the choice of the user... but how do i put this into a variable?
    }(i + 1 + " " + arrFiltered[i]);  

}
```

Thanks,
Ewan

Comment: You might want to post your HTML code as well, so we can see what these document elements are. If you want to get the choice (value) from a dropDown box, that's straight-forward.

Comment: HI Jedison, firstly thanks for the reply. I have posted my HTML. The Javascript populates the div boxes with data from the database and then (look at the last line of my javascript) I can console log their choice but cant get that choice out of the for loop. This is where i am lost.

Comment: I'm guessing your problem is that the classText's do not have a name nor id, so the Javascript (`classText[i].innerHTML = arrFiltered[i] || "";`) can't get their value.

Comment: So do something like this in the HTML.             <div id="searchBox">
`<div class="searchBoxModule" onclick="firstBox()">
    <a class='searchText' id="searchText1"></a>
</div>`

Comment: Thanks, extracting the HTML after it has been inserted, clever. Put it as an answer and i'll say it is the correct answer if you want points for the help. foo = document.getElementById('searchText1'); console.log(foo.innerHTML);

Comment: Hi @Ewan, when you get a chance, if that works, you can check off my answer and perhaps vote it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is with this

```
(classText[i].innerHTML = arrFiltered[i] || "";)
```

not being able to get the innerHTML.
So do something like this in the HTML.

```
<div id="searchBox"> 
<div class="searchBoxModule" onclick="firstBox()">
<a class='searchText' id="searchText1"></a> 
</div>
```

then you can easily do:

```
foo = document.getElementById('searchText1');
```

Comment: NO PROBLEM! I am not a point hound, but would like to get into the "K" (> 1000) zone someday.